# unexpected token: '2015-07-28'

Tags: apex, soql, query

```
String query= 'Select Id from Account where isNew__c = true and Start_Date__c <:'+ Date.today() +' or End_Date__c <: '+ Date.today() ';
```

What I'm I missing in this query? I tried using a date field instead of Date.today() but still get the same error.

Comment: The colons should not be there when the query already contains literal values. They are used for binding variables into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark was right but you need to wrap the OR in parentheses.

`String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE isNew__c = true AND (Start_Date__c < TODAY OR End_Date__c < TODAY)';`

Answer (score 2):

The colons should be removed, they're used for binding variables. You've got literal date values being used, not variables.

That said, you also could use the [SOQL date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) `TODAY` in your query string directly.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE isNew__c = true AND Start_Date__c < TODAY OR End_Date__c < TODAY';
```

Comment: That throws System.QueryException: unexpected token: OR